# Select newest datetime for each userid MS Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, select

I have a table used for a chat. Among others there is a field called userid and a field called timesent. I need to know the latest timesent for each userid in the table, so that I can delete them from the table if they haven't said anything for 3 minutes, in which case I will assume they are gone.

I can't really crack this nut... How do I query.

I could of course split it up and first select all the userids and then loop through them and select top 1 timesent in my method, but I was wondering if sql alone can do the trick, so I don't need to execute tons of queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the latest `timesent` per `userid` you can use `MAX`

```
SELECT userid, MAX(timesent) AS timesent
FROM your_table
GROUP BY userid
```

Or to do the specified `delete` you can use

```
DELETE your_table 
FROM   your_table y1 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                  FROM   your_table y2 
                  WHERE  y2.userid = y1.userid 
                         AND y2.timesent >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -3, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: I don't really follow the last one but it sounds good, there are actually two tables, one is called chatroom (what they say) and the other chatroomin (who's in the room). If latest timesent in chatroom is more than 3 minutes old, the user(id) should be deleted from chatroomin, can you modify the sql to this setup?

Comment: `DELETE chatroomin FROM chatroomin y1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM chatroom y2 WHERE y2.userid=y1.userid AND y2.timesent >= DATEADD(MINUTE,-3,GETDATE()) )`

Comment: nice... Even better. Thanks again :)